# UILabel sizeToFit break constraints only on ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uilabel

I have an iOS app almos finished, but i found a bug. I have an UITableView with an prototype cell and an UILabel on the cell. In runtime i put text in the label and use the method **`sizeToFit()`** to resize the label. This **`works fine on iOS8`** but on iOS7 a get an **`error of breaking constrains`** and the UILabel simply not resize.

I need your help, its the only thing that i have to do to publish the app.

**The constrains :**

```
UILabel to top of cell content - 10 

UILabel to bottom of cell content - 10 

UILabel to left of cell content - 5

UILabel to right of cell content - 5
```

P.S - I don't have an cell height defined and i don't use the `method estimatedCellSize`.

Comment: why do you need to call sizeToFit?

Comment: Because te text its added on run time and i dont know the text length, i use it to resize the label to fit the text.

Comment: Nothing to do with Swing.  Please **read** the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on a question.

Comment: I wanted to set "Swift", sorry was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
use label.numberoflines=0;
labe.sizeToFit=YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be changing your constraints or your approach.

Either use the compression and hugging constraint values to make the label size to fit, and remove the constraints to the right and bottom (in this case to pin the label to the top left and resize).

Or, keep the current constraints and change the label to scale its contents to fit.

Comment: You can give me an example of how i do the second option?

Comment: Set `minimumFontScale` (in IB or code) - this deals with too much text, but it doesn't fit to small text - you don't actually state exactly why you size to fit

Comment: I want to UILabel adjust her size to the text content and the cell adjust her size to the new size of UILabel.

Comment: The cell will not adjust height unless you implement the appropriate delegate method